# Is using WebAuthn alone considered as two factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, fido

Will using WebAuthn for an application make it two factor? I am specifically interested in using Ondevice biometrics and achieve passwordless authentication.

For a true two factor authentication you need one to use two of the three forms of authentication: "something you know", "something you have" and "something you are".

When using WebAuthn using on-device biometrics, can we call the device that I am using to access the portal as "something you have" and the biometric as "something you are"?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193584/arent-endpoint-devices-inherently-mfa

Comment: Depending on how you are implementing your system, the authentication system itself cannot be considered one of the factors.

Comment: @schroeder : thanks for providing the above article

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aren't endpoint devices inherently MFA?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193584/arent-endpoint-devices-inherently-mfa)

Answer (score 2):

WebAuthn by itself, no. WebAuthn is simply a public-key-based authentication method with some requirements for how the proof of ownership occurs. You can, for example, use WebAuthn with a hardware token such as a Yubikey and get only single-factor auth (assuming no passphrase is required on the hardware token). Apple's recent innovation of roaming your WebAuthn private keys through iCloud means that an attacker with only a user's password could also do WebAuthn as only a single factor (password, no need for a device the victim actually owns).

WebAuthn *where you require that the private key be protected by some other factor* such as a fingerprint is... sort of 1.5 factor? In the case of a compliant client, it's going to require multiple factors. However, the *server has no way to know*. The client could be somebody furiously typing into `ncat`, copy-pasting the signed data out of the `openssl` command-line tool, for all you know. In practice, people don't usually worry about this - if some user wants to go well out of their way to use a client that fraudulently *claims* to be requiring multiple factors, that's on the user's head and not your problem - but it does become an issue if there's a risk that the key could be stolen. For example, consider the biometric case. The server has *no idea* what the user's fingerprint looks like; that's never transmitted to them. Instead, the client captures the fingerprint, checks it against the stored fingerprint data, and uses the private key if there's a match. If an attacker can steal that private key out of your client, the attacker can simply *pretend* that there's still a fingerprint involved, but really there isn't. The only credential *that the server actually checks* is whether the client has the right private key.

Now, in practice, most devices these days store the private key in a secure enclave, a hardware-protected region of modern CPUs and HSMs where the key can't be exfiltrated, and where code that can't be tampered with by other code can run (such as fingerprint-comparison code). Stealing keys out of a secure enclave, or fooling the secure enclave into thinking that you're the legitimate user of that key when you're not, is as-close-as-they-can-make-it-to impossible. As such, you're probably not at risk of a user's key being extracted from a stolen device and used without the user's fingerprint, or at least without *some* other credential of the user's (such as a device unlock PIN/swipe pattern, which in many cases can be used as an alternative to fingerprints to unlock WebAuthn platform credentials); given that, it's *almost* as good as true MFA.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if you are limiting access to your service by devices by some reasonable method.

If you have to use a domain joined laptop then probably yes. If you are using an app on a mobile device, then using the native biometrics capability to encrypt a secret then probably yes.

Comment: Thanks @ste-fu .That helps. Also, in order to compromise my access a bad actor will need to possess both my device (since I had enrolled my biometrics only on that device) and my biometric (e.,g fingerprint) - thus making it a two factor authentication.