# MFA: can unique biometrics collecting device count as another authentication factor (a possession factor)?

Tags: multi-factor, biometrics

I see in this answer ([Aren't endpoint devices inherently MFA?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193584/arent-endpoint-devices-inherently-mfa)) that an endpoint device doesn't qualify as an authentication factor (AF). But if the endpoint biometric collecting device is uniquely registered with an entity, e.g. with an id number, then does it count as an AF?

(related to [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7038220&tag=1))

The paper uses two AFs which are user biometrics and a system symmetric key. But the authentication is vehicle to infrastructure or vehicle to vehicle, so it doesn't actually need to identify the driver in authentication. If it's only authenticating the identity of the vehicle, which has a uniquely registered biometric collecting terminal with an id number, does the terminal count as an AF? Should the human biometrics be counted as an AF for the vehicle authentication?